Setting a Variable based on user input from one visual only
I have a report that has a Display Currency selection on it, using a slicer. The user can choose between USD $ and GBP £. Depending on the option chosen, visuals will sum over either a column of US Dollar or GBP Values. So, if USD is selected, the visual might show $120, or £100 for example.
The problem that I have is that whenever the user selects an element on another visual, it reverts the selected currency back to the default (GBP). This is because I'm using the SELECTEDVALUE function, but of course the SELECTEDVALUE changes when the user clicks on another visual. This happens whether or not there's any relationships or interactions defined between the visuals.
I ideally want to avoid having to create a duplicated report in both currencies and use bookmarks to move between the two, as it's clunky and frustrating to build.
Ideally, I want to have a variable in the background that stores the value of the specific slicer that controls the currency view, so that any other slicer selections will not alter that value. Is this possible?

I have used field parameters to filter across the different visuals but this still causes the value to "reset" every time the user clicks another visual/slicer

Can you provide some data ? and your calculations?

Can you please provide the file as well?

@NickA unfortunately due to restrictive company security policies I can't do any uploads via filesharing etc. Basically though, the data can be anything at all - I did a mockup for the screenshot with two slicers and a card - one table with simply two rows (USD | GBP) and the other with three groups and some random numbers for "values". Added a Measure to the Currency table for SELECTEDVALUE('Currency') which is the value in the Card visual (shows whichever was selected on the US/GB slicer).

@AmiraBedhiafi - the data I used for the example was just dummy data - one table with two rows (GBP | USD) and one with Groups 1-3 with random numbers. The only other element then is a Measure for SELECTEDVALUE('Currency') from the 1st table. I come mostly from a coding background, so I'm looking for something like "If Slicer1.SelecedValue = USD then [change variable value to GBP]" triggered on the event of a user changing the slicer value of Slicer1

I see you are using the Enlighten World Flag Slicer, which unfortunately works more like a visual than a slicer. It unselects your previous selection when selecting other visuals.
I recommend creating a Tile Slicer and using image URLs as the slicer. Here is a quick explanation:
Add an Image URL of the flag to your table.



Currency Code
Country
Image




USD
USA
!https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Flag_of_the_United_States_%28DoS_ECA_Color_Standard%29.svg/255px-Flag_of_the_United_States_%28DoS_ECA_Color_Standard%29.svg.png


GBP
UK
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom_%281-2%29.svg/640px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom_%281-2%29.svg.png



In Table View, select the Image column and change the data type to "Image URL".

Create a Tile Slicer and use the new Image URL column in the slicer. It will automatically show the flag. Then you can resize and change the borders as needed.

For a more detailed walkthrough, check out this video.

Excellent, thank you for this answer!
